# Changing biblatex style for one slide

Tags: beamer, biblatex

In a presentation created with the `beamer` class, I'm using

```
\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

and

```
\footcite{source}
```

`style=verbose` is required so that author, title and so on show up in the foot note and not just a number indicating the source.

However, on one slide a give an overview of different algorithms, which requires a lot of citations. Only for this slide I'd like to use `\cite`, which should give me e.g. `[1]` in the text, but no footnote. The problem is that thanks to `style=verbose`, `\cite` inserts author, title and so on instead of a short number.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you change to `style=numeric-comp` and use `\fullfootcite` on all slides you want the verbose output you can use `\cite` on your overview slide.

Comment: I can't get `fullfootcite`to work. Do I need an additional import?

Comment: This may be because of my typo. Try `\footfullcite` instead. Sorry.

Comment: Works! You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your implementation of biblatex to

```
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

Then you can cite on the overview slide with

```
\cite{<key>}
```

or

```
\autocite{<key>}
```

if you want to specify style commands as options in the preamble, e.g.

```
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,
            autocite=superscript, % apply options here
            backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

And when a full citation is necessary you can cite with

```
\footfullcite{<key>}
```